# Как сделать что бы видео нельзя было скачать с сайта?

Tags: html

Как сделать что бы видео нельзя было скачать с сайта?

Comment: Чтобы посмотреть видео на сайте было можно а скачать нельзя? Похоже что никак. :-) Но за разработку такой технологии студия Метро Голдвин Майер заплатит сто миллионов долларов не торгуясь. Так что пробуйте. :-)

Comment: Тотальный DRM на каждом шаге просмотра видео, от скачивания зашифрованного контента до зашифрованного видеопотока в HDMI-кабеле с работой только на сертифицированных ПО и устройствах) Но если вы простой смертный, то вам ничего такого не светит (и всё равно останется возможность тупо заснять монитор/телевизор на обычную видеокамеру)

Comment: Есть промышленый вариант шифровки видео - платные телеканалы с тарелки. Можно почитать как обстоят дела с просмотром НТВ+ и взломом платных спутниковых каналов. Возможно скоро появятся (если не уже появились) кардридеры для платных карт для компа, которые содержат ключ. Но записать что на "видеовыходе" всеравно можно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запарольте доступ к нему и никому не говорите пароль — не скачают. :)

На самом деле, ответ «никак» или около того. Действительно, если вы передаёте байты видеопотока клиенту для просмотра, то сохранение клиентом этих байт себе на диск — лишь вопрос его желания (пример — youtube). Отсюда, казалось бы, возможный вариант — предоставление всем заинтересованным в просмотре специального клиента, который разрабатываете вы сам, и только вы знаете, как декодировать/дешифровать поступающий видеопоток. Однако, разработка такого клиента под всё множество имеющихся платформ — дело недешёвое, значит, ваша услуга показа видео тоже будет стоить денег. Отсюда опять два варианта: либо оно будет никому не интересно за эти деньги, и никто не будет покупать вашу услугу, либо ваш клиент среверсят и напишут свой, бесплатный, с сохранением.

Comment: [предоставление всем заинтересованным в просмотре специального клиента] Всегда можно подключиться к видеовыходу и записать видеопоток на диск. На монитор-то он уже незашифрованный идет.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 смотря на какой монитор. А вот в глаз идёт _всегда_ незашифрованный — это да, это проблема.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 на монитор может идти и зашифрованный https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDCP *(да, там написано, что взломано в 2010-м, но всё ж сам факт)*

Comment: @Alexander Prokoshev Обычный монитор. Если сайт открывается на десктопном компе, то значит что у компа есть монитор. К монитору идет HDMI кабель. К этому кабелю подключаете расстыковку и сливаете видеопоток на диск. И никакое шифрование не поможет. Это не говоря уже о том, что в линуксе оконная система может цепляться через сеть и там для перехвата видеопотока надо просто Ethernet сниффить. А для сниффинга давно есть программно-аппаратные инструменты.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 в HDMI-кабеле сигнал зашифрованный — см. выше

Comment: @pepsicoca1 не уверен, что можно программно отличить HDMI-монитор от VGA, но при тех бюджетах, о которых мы говорим, уже можно реально влиять на запрещение производства VGA-мониторов по всему миру. А для линуксов всё равно такие вещи никто писать не будет, потому что в тех линупсах заведомо одни хакиры и биткойновые анонимусы, нифига не потребляющие легальный платный контент и вынашивающие зловещие планы.

Comment: @andreymal [HDMI-кабеле сигнал зашифрованный] Поставьте видеокарту с аналоговым выходом SVGA и перехватите аналоговый  SVGA-сигнал. Он то точно не зашифрован. :-)

Comment: @Alexander Prokoshev [для линуксов всё равно такие вещи никто писать не будет] Давно уже написаны все снифферы.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 я и говорю — анонимусы, диджитал резистанс и зловещие планы смотрения того, что смотреть им не положено :)

Comment: Кстати, для Windows скорее всего можно тоже оконную систему через сеть подключить. Во всяком случае в приснопамятной Windows XP для встраиваемых систем такая опция была.

Comment: @Alexander Prokoshev [диджитал резистанс и зловещие планы] Отступать некуда, позади Москва! Запретить деление ПО на слои и зашифровать всю операционную систему на уровне БИОС.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 а на SVGA DRM-плеер просто откажется запускаться ;)

Comment: @andreymal Есть карты с двумя выходами цифровым и аналоговым. Если припрет, то можно подцепиться к монитору после расшифровки и перехватить сигнал на матрице. Конечно, это потребует денег, но сделать это можно и не так уж и дорого будет. Но проще на линуксе подключить монитор по Ethernet и снять всю информацию.